# Should we commit PreviewProvider struct to version control system Git when using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

Should I allow my team members to commit a debug PreviewProvider struct to git?

```
 #if DEBUG
    struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    #endif
```

Comment: Why not? The preview in Xcode 11 won't work without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes. The `PreviewProvider` is required for the live preview to work.

This would be a big loose of time if each member of your team as to rewrite its own code to be able to use the live preview.

And as it is part of the code, I can't think of any downside of having it shared across the team.